# Can a meterpreter session be reopened?

Tags: session-management, kali-linux, meterpreter

I tried to hack multiple android phones using .apk files but everytime the session lasts 5-10 seconds:

> [*] 94.243.71.172 - Meterpreter session 1 closed.  Reason: Died

Then, to open a new session I need to uninstall and then reinstall the .apk file again. But it's impossible to do this on the victim's phone (I don't have physical access to it).

So how can I open a new session without reinstalling the .apk file on android, and why it lasts so few?

Comment: We can't possibly know how to help with so little information. All you've told us is that the session dies.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you created the apk in the wrong way I think. Usually if you create a apk using Msfvenom, the meterpreter session is not opened on install. It's opened once app is launched.

Anyway, the result of creating a Meterpreter apk using Msfvenom is too suspecting... an app what is doing apparently nothing with a blank screen... you better should try to decompile an existing apk and then inserting the meterpreter code inside it and repack. The meterpreter session will remain while the app is open. To do that try this manual (two parts):

- https://techkernel.org/2015/12/11/embed-metasploit-payload-in-apk-easily/
- https://techkernel.org/2015/12/19/embed-metasploit-payload-in-apk-manually/

Good luck